# How is bulk capacitance for a brushed DC motor H-Bridge calculated in the real world?

Tags: dc-motor, h-bridge, electrolytic-capacitor

There's a lot of great information on driving DC brushed motors from h-bridges. Preventing back-emf with diodes and bulk capacitance from electrolytic capacitors

When designing a high powered h bridge driver, people agree that bulk capacitance is required. It helps absorb the power surges when changes directions, braking, or back-emf. It also helps to avoid a voltage sag on the main rail.

It seems that people will throw as much large electrolytics in parallel as they can, hoping it is enough. To calculate how much is required, there isn't much information available. Other than saying the peak current, wire inductance, battery impedance, etc is required, then not showing what to do with that.

Is there any practical way to determine the amount of bulk capacitance required? My application is a super compact, 45A+ 4s H-Bridge driver. I can't afford the space to just blindly throw capacitors on and hope for the best.

I know there's not a great exact way to calculate this, but there has to be some way to get close.

Comment: Do you have a resistor bank or mechanical brake to absorb the kinetic energy when slowing (or changing direction)?  If not, you have to size your cap bank to handle the worst-case regenerative energy without exceeding the design voltage of your driver stage.  Otherwise your source impedance and your system specs like torque ripple will dictate how much capacitance you need.

Comment: @JohnD So for the sake of this, no I won't have a resistor bank. So is it an energy from the motor to the capacitors equation then? Also, without braking, then what is the limiting factor?

Comment: You can also use a (fat) zener diode instead of capacitors to clamp to voltage.

Comment: @Huisman One near the power supply enterance of the board?

Comment: No, it's a counter measure against regenerative energy. So, it  should be located where the motor wires leave/enter the PCB.

Comment: @Huisman Well I'm talking about a H-Bridge with forward and reverse, so can't do the diode right at the motor. Can do it across each FET, but for braking, you still need somewhere for the energy to go

Comment: My bad being unclear: it should of course be between the power rails of the H-bridge... I assumed the  the motors leads being close to the H-bridge as well.

Comment: @Huisman Because something like this to my knowledge, still will require bulk capacitance. Which goes back to my question of, how much? http://i.imgur.com/QZbIC.jpg

Comment: @KyleHunter Yep, figure the kinetic energy in your motor and load, subtract system losses and size your cap bank so that the delta in voltage from absorbing that much energy doesn't smoke your H-bridge.  You might decide you need a resistor bank or other type of clamp.  If the regen energy isn't an issue then voltage ripple on your supply rail will be the limiting factor and sizing the caps so the voltage doesn't crater or cause tourque ripple (because you can't get the current you want) will dictate the amount of cap required.

Comment: @JohnD Not to sound like a jerk, but those are the types of answers/info that stemmed my question. There's really not a practical way - that I have heard/seen - to do those calculations. Hence why people seem to just throw caps on randomly and pray.

Comment: @KyleHunter Sure, but there are the laws of physics, there’s no magic to it.  First order calculations followed by system testing, no magic formula.

Comment: @KyleHunter And the kinetic energy you need to absorb might not be that hard to calculate.  Then E=1/2CV^2.

Comment: @JohnD The E=1/2CV^2 only applies when the caps are 0V initially...

Comment: @Huisman sure, you need to look at the delta in energy and voltage.

Comment: See https://www.ecicaps.com/wp-content/uploads/IEMDC_2009_11310_Final_Rev_4.pdf for a pretty good explanation.

Comment: What did you end up doing Kyle?

Answer (score 1):

> My application is a super compact, 45A+ 4s H-Bridge driver.

By '4S' I presume you mean a 14.8 V Li-ion battery. This is good because the battery makes a relatively 'stiff' power source (unlike a power supply which might not be able to absorb much current). The main problem you have is the inductance of the battery leads, and the main thing to worry about is the voltage rating of the H-bridge FETs.

When PWM is applied the battery current is a 'square' wave, and the simplified circuit looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdrcFS.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

At the moment the FET switches off the battery current will start dropping, but this induces a voltage across the inductor which prevents the current from dropping instantly. The current then flows through the bulk capacitor which drops voltage across its internal resistance, raising the input voltage of the controller.

If the current was 45 A and the capacitor ESR was 1 Ω then the voltage would momentarily rise by 45 V. Since the capacitor is already charged up to battery voltage, the controller input voltage would rise to 14.8 + 45 = ~60 V. If the FET is only rated for 30 V then you have a problem! When the FET is turned on a similar action occurs, only this time the controller input voltage drops - possibly low enough to upset its operation - or even go negative and blow up components. So the main thing you need is low enough ESR to keep the voltage spikes down.

Secondary requirement is enough capacitance to not charge significantly as the inductance discharges. If that happens you get ringing, which can raise the peak voltage even with (or even more with) low ESR. Increasing capacitance lowers Q and reduces ringing.

For normal wiring lengths with the wires close together to minimize loop inductance, if Al electrolytic capacitors are used then once you have low enough ESR the capacitance will probably be large enough. So just calculate the required ESR, eg.:-

FET voltage rating 30 V, derate to 25 V for safety. Maximum pulse current 45 A, maximum battery voltage 16.8 V, maximum permissible voltage rise 25 - 16.8 = ~8 V. 8 / 45 = 0.18 Ω total ESR.

Final issue is capacitor ripple current, which depends on battery ESR, wiring inductance, and PWM frequency, as well as capacitance and capacitor ESR. We could do all the calculations to work it out by hand, but it would be tedious. To calculate wiring inductance, go [here](https://www.eeweb.com/tools/parallel-wire-inductance). A good simulator can do the calculations for you if everything is set up right, but it might be quicker and easier to just blindly throw as many capacitors on as you can and see what happens!

Comment: Thanks for this info. But the motor should also have an inductor in series with the resistor. That's where the main voltage spike will come from.

Comment: There is a flyback diode that shunts the inductive spike spike from the motor, so the motor side of the FET only goes down to slightly below 0 volts.The only time a higher voltage comes out of the controller is if regenerative braking is applied, using PWM on the low side FET to boost the motor voltage. This would not be a problem either if there was no lead inductance, since the battery acts like a capacitor which absorbs the boost current.

Comment: Just to be clear, I didn't include motor inductance in my simplified circuit because it's irrelevant to this part of the controller. If I was simulating the entire system then of course I would include it (along with generator voltage, motor internal resistance, FET characteristics etc.)

Comment: This doesnt seem right. I think the motor's inductance will cause a current to flow through the diodes of two of the mosfets back into the battery, and as a motor has higher inductance than the wire the current path wont be forced through the capacitor

Answer (score -1):

Does your system design include ground planes?

Does your wiring  plan include TWISTED PAIRS, to minimize inductance?

Have you yet to draw a complete sketch of wiring, so distances(inductances) can be estimated?

Have you ever used the math

Vspike = L * dI/dT

and examined the result

V = 100 nanoHenries * 100 amps/100 nanoseconds

> > === 100 volt across the 100nH

which about 4" (100milliMeters) of single-run wire.

The value of twisted pairs is the reduction of that 100 nanoHenries/100milliMeters by a significant fraction (the fraction depends on many factors).

===================================

What does this mean? place the snubbers within 10mm (1cm) of the spikey node, to drop the voltage-spike amplitude down to only 10 volts.

=====================================

How close can you place the AC_DC power supply? If that DC output can be 10cm away from the H-bridge, do you need bulk capacitors other than what are in the AC_DC regulator?

Otherwise some group of capacitors must store enough charge, to ensure only 5 volts sag, or 1 volt sag, between Switching Regulator output periods. So lets discuss that.

Suppose your AC_DC regulator switches at 100,000 cycles per second (in the new age, about 1965, that was changed to Hertz), thus the AC_DC regulator (might be able to) react to load changes in 1/100,000 second (maybe) or 10 microSeconds.
And assume you will tolerate 1 volt ripple on the VDD to the Hbridge. At 45 amps.

Use Q = C *  V, differentiate to get

dQ/dT = C * dV/dT + V * dC/dT

and discard the 2nd term (we'll assume the cap value is not a strong function of voltage). We now have what we can use

dQ/dT = I = C * dV/dT

and rewrite to have C = I * dT /dV

and substitute

C = 45 amps * 10 microseconds / 1 volt

C = 450 microFarads

Comment: Yes to twisted pairs, yes to ground planes. For the drawing, sure, but I need to know the calculations to do with what I get. So if I use that calculation you give, what do I do with the vspike to get capacitance required?